# Downloading manifest for a video with youtube-dl

Tags: youtube-dl

I am interested in extracting the manifest file from YouTube videos by using youtube-dl.

The problem I am experiencing is that according to the API the manifest is automatically included in the JSON file that I download. But, when I look at it I can't find any part called "manifest". Is my code or am I looking for the information the wrong way?

Code line (with example):

```
youtube-dl --write-info-json -f 133 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AJ7skYS5bjI
```

My expectation is that the JSON file that is downloaded should have a "manifest" parameter. But when I search for it, nothing is found.

Comment: Your command doesn't download any json file, what exactly are you talking about ?

Comment: my mistake, now I have corrected the command line